# Trying to figure out if a sequence of numbers can exist with specific criterion

Tags: matlab, math

Let's say I have a sequence of 72 numbers and they can be numbers 1 through 6. I also have very specific criterion that I want met within this sequence of 72 numbers.

The criterion is based off of number matches between N (current number), and N-1 (previous number), N-2 (previous number 2 back), and N-3 (previous number 3 back).

So, for example a sequence of 1 5 6 6 5 2 5 would contain matches for N-1 (6 6), N-2 (5 2 5), and N-3 (5 6 6 5). It would also contain no matches for N-3 (1 5 6 6, 6 6 5 2, 6 5 2 5). Which I am interested in as well.

Does anyone have any suggestions of a method to test if it is even possible, with a sequence of 72 numbers to meet the criterion below?

```
N-1 trial   N-2 trial   N-3 trial       Occurrences 
No Match    No Match    No Match        30  
Match       No Match    No Match        6   
No Match    Match       No Match        6   
No Match    No Match    Match           6   
Match       Match       No Match        6   
No Match    Match       Match           6   
Match       No Match    Match           6   
Match       Match       Match           6
```

So, for example the first condition (no match, no match, no match) would occur 30 times in the sequences of 72 numbers.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit** I do have a brute force script in Matlab that can run through random iterations and ends when it is successful. But I am just not sure how to test if a sequence of 72 numbers can even exist and meet those criteria.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to *generate* such a sequence, or how to *test* if a given sequence meets these criteria?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification. I have a script that can generate random sequences and then test it to see if it meets those criteria and it works really well with less strict criteria. But the script is not able to determine if such a sequence can even exist.

Comment: For `N < 4` do you count `N-3` as a "no match" even though `N-3` is undefined? In any event, there is something graph-theoretic about the question. It is a type of node coloring problem in a directed graph with 72 nodes where you have 6 colors.

Comment: You are correct that N-3 would be undefined. Thank you for the tip to look at graph-theory. I will investigate that and see if I am able to figure anything out.